# Easiest way to implode() a two-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP, and don't have quite the grip on how it works.  If I have a two dimensional array as such (returned by a database):

```
array(3) {   
    [0]=> array(1) {         
        ["tag_id"]=> string(1) "5" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) {         
        ["tag_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(1) {         
        ["tag_id"]=> string(1) "4" 
    } 
}
```

and want to turn it into the string `5,3,4` what would be the quickest way do do this?  I currently have an obnoxious `foreach` loop, but was hoping it could be done in one line.  A standard `implode` gives me `Array,Array,Array`.

Comment: You can remove all the line breaks in your `foreach`.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you shouldn't care if something uses a couple of lines.

Comment: @Xeon06 While I agree on principle, I'd like to see if there's a nifty way to do it better.  Half of this project is learning, the other half is actual coding.  (Even better, I could remove all the line breaks and tell my boss that the code only needed a one-liner)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This modifies your array using [array_map](http://php.net/array-map), but probably for the better by turning it into a 1D array of `tag_id`'s. Then you can just use implode like normal:

```
$arr = array_map(function($el){ return $el['tag_id']; }, $arr);
$str = implode(',', $arr);
```

If you don't want to modify your array than you can just do this:

```
$str = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el['tag_id']; }, $arr));
```

[**Codepad Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DJZzqi)

Comment: Well, you can actually pass the result of `array_map` right into `implode` call. )

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, but I think it might be better to modify the original array since the extra dimension seems useless. I'll update my answer though :)

Answer (score 8):

You asked for a two-dimensional array, here's a function that will work for multidimensional array.

```
function implode_r($g, $p) {
    return is_array($p) ?
           implode($g, array_map(__FUNCTION__, array_fill(0, count($p), $g), $p)) : 
           $p;
}
```

I can flatten an array structure like so:

```
$multidimensional_array = array(
    'This',
    array(
        'is',
        array(
            'a',
            'test'
        ),
        array(
            'for',
            'multidimensional',
            array(
                'array'
            )
        )
    )
);

echo implode_r(',', $multidimensional_array);
```

The results is:

```
This,is,a,test,for,multidimensional,array
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// simplest
$str = implode(',',array_map('implode',$arr));
```

Answer (score 6):

If one simply wants to implode a single array "column" as in this case, then the simplest thing to do is:

```
implode(",", array_column($array,"tag_id"));
```

Answer (score 3):

One line command

```
implode(',', array_map('implode', $arr, array_fill(0, count($arr), '')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the below from the [PHP implode() manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#106085):

```
<?php
/**
 * Implode an array with the key and value pair giving
 * a glue, a separator between pairs and the array
 * to implode.
 * @param string $glue The glue between key and value
 * @param string $separator Separator between pairs
 * @param array $array The array to implode
 * @return string The imploded array
 */
function array_implode( $glue, $separator, $array ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $array ) ) return $array;
    $string = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
        if ( is_array( $val ) )
            $val = implode( ',', $val );
        $string[] = "{$key}{$glue}{$val}";

    }
    return implode( $separator, $string );

}
?>
```

If you only want to return the value (and not the key), just modify the above to use `$string[] = "{$val}";`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursive_implode($connector=',', $array=[], $implod='keys'){

    if($implod=='keys'){

        $results=implode($connector,array_keys($array));
    }
    else{

        $results=implode($connector,$array);
    }

    foreach($array as $key=> $value){

        if(is_array($value)){

            $results.=$connector.recursive_implode($connector,$value,$implod);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```