# Implode two-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => e
            [2] => f
        )

)
```

I want to convert my array to a string like below:

```
$arrtostr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
```

I've used `implode()` function but it looks like it doesn't work on two-dimensional arrays.

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to implode() a two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038282/easiest-way-to-implode-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use a container for that first, merge the contents, and in the end of having a flat one, then use `implode()`:

```
$letters = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $letters = array_merge($letters, $value);
}

echo implode(', ', $letters);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Na26hg)

Answer (score 1):

Given your subject array:

```
$subject = array(
    array('a', 'b'),
    array('c'),
    array('d', 'e', 'f'),
);
```

Two easy ways to get a "flattened" array are:

**PHP 5.6.0 and above** using the [splat operator](http://php.net/...):

```
$flat = array_merge(...$subject);
```

**Lower than PHP 5.6.0** using [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $subject);
```

Both of these give an array like:

```
$flat = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

Then to get your string, just implode:

```
$string = implode(',', $flat);
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a two-dimensional array, here's a function that will work for multidimensional array.

```
function implode_r($g, $p) {
    return is_array($p) ?
           implode($g, array_map(__FUNCTION__, array_fill(0, count($p), $g), $p)) : 
           $p;
}
```

I can flatten an array structure like so:

```
$multidimensional_array = array(
    'This',
    array(
        'is',
        array(
            'a',
            'test'
        ),
        array(
            'for',
            'multidimensional',
            array(
                'array'
            )
        )
    )
);

echo implode_r(',', $multidimensional_array);
```

The results is:

```
This,is,a,test,for, multidimensional,array
```