# SQL JOIN result keeps repeating

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In my database I have 3 tables: `user`, `phone` and `number`. Their structure accordingly:

```
ID | name
---+------
 1 | Joe
 2 | Gin
 3 | Ash


ID |   Brand   | series
---+-----------+--------
 1 |  Samsung  | s7
 2 |  Iphone   | 6s
 3 |  Samsung  | s5


ID |  number   
---+----------
 1 |  77612  
 2 |  34014  
 3 |  98271
```

What I want to do is select using `JOIN`. Here is my attempt:

```
$query = "SELECT u.id, p.brand, n.number
          FROM `user` u 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `phone` p
              ON u.id = p.id
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `number` n 
              ON p.id = n.id
          WHERE u.id = '$selected'";

$sql = mysql_query($query);

if ($sql === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}

while ($result = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
    $final[] = $result;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($final);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Where `$selected` is an array of arrays from form input that allows to choose what `ID`'s to show, for example:

```
$selected = array(1, 3);
```

But the result is:

```
Array (
      [0] => Array (
          [0] => 1
          [1] => Samsung
          [2] => 77612
      )
    )
Array (
      [0] => Array (
          [0] => 1
          [1] => Samsung
          [2] => 77612
      )
      [1] => Array (
          [0] => 3
          [1] => Samsung
          [2] => 98271
      )
)
```

If we set `$selected = array(1, 2, 3)`, the output will be the same as shown above. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
$selected =  array(array(1), array(2), array(3));

// make list of id from source array
$selected = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $selected);
$selected = implode(',', $selected); // 1,2,3
```

and change where clause to

```
WHERE u.id in ($selected)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responds.. I got some mistake on $selected array structure. Here, i already edited it `$selected = array(1, 2, 3)` :)
By the way, i tried yours, and it appears `array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in...`

Comment: in that case dont use the 1st line. just `$selected = implode(',', $selected); // 1,2,3 `

Comment: I tried it, but it appears an error `Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'`, D:

Comment: Here it is `SELECT u.id, p.brand, n.number FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN phone p ON u.id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN number n ON p.id = n.id WHERE u.id u.id IN (1,2)`

Comment: `WHERE u.id u.id IN (1,2)` have to be `WHERE u.id IN (1,2)`

Comment: Oops sorry my mistake, i double u.id in this comment, but in my code `WHERE u.id IN ($selected)`

Comment: Yep, anyway it works, i add "" in `implode("','", $selected)` and add '' in `('selected')`. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to structure your ids seperated by commas. For this purpose I'm using the following function found in [Easiest way to implode() a two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038282/easiest-way-to-implode-a-two-dimensional-array)

```
function implode_r($g, $p) {
    return is_array($p) ?
           implode($g, array_map(__FUNCTION__, array_fill(0, count($p), $g), $p)) : 
           $p;
}
```

Then you have to change a little bit your query using the keyword [IN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm):

```
$ids=implode_r(",",$selected);

$query = "SELECT u.id, p.brand, n.number FROM `user` u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `phone` p ON u.id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN `number` n 
ON p.id = n.id WHERE u.id in ($ids)";
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responds.. I got some mistake on $selected array structure. Here, i already edited it `$selected = array(1, 2, 3)` :)

Comment: Then you can use the simple implode function. $ids=implode(",", $selected).

Comment: Yup, i already tried it, but it appears `Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @KirariAkito What type are the IDs in your table. They should be integers. I guess they are strings